# postgres checkpointer process exited with exit code 0

Tags: postgresql

I have a website using postgresql on vps. at the same time 2 days in a row I get an error and the postgres server reboots

**1 day:**

```
2019-03-15 05:58:53.305 UTC [1329] LOG:  shutting down
2019-03-15 05:58:53.313 UTC [1311] LOG:  checkpointer process (PID 1329) exited with exit code 0
2019-03-15 05:58:53.313 UTC [1311] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2019-03-15 05:58:53.314 UTC [6441] retouch@retouch_db WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2019-03-15 05:58:53.314 UTC [6441] retouch@retouch_db DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another
 server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
```

**2 day:**

```
2019-03-16 05:53:10.368 UTC [16248] LOG:  shutting down
2019-03-16 05:53:10.375 UTC [16245] LOG:  checkpointer process (PID 16248) exited with exit code 0
2019-03-16 05:53:10.375 UTC [16245] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2019-03-16 05:53:10.376 UTC [25344] retouch@retouch_db WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2019-03-16 05:53:10.376 UTC [25344] retouch@retouch_db DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because anothe
r server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
```

I do load testing of the site and make a stream of requests directly to the database and it works well. But for 2 days in a row at a certain time I get an error restarting the server

The server has enough memory to start the server. The charts show that the memory not runs out, and in dmesg there is no record of postgres

Comment: First, check syslog. Could be that the OOM-killer kicked in. [and: *(crystal ball...)* you should probably lower work_mem and the number of connected sessions]

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Problem solved. 
The VPS management server was configured incorrectly


syslog:
Mar 17 09:56:08 server-name qemu-ga: info: guest-exec called: "pidof postgres"
Mar 17 09:56:09 server-name qemu-ga: info: guest-exec called: “kill -s SIGUSR2 18174 18173 18172 18169 18168 18167 18166 18165 18164 18160 18159 18158 18157 18156 18155 18154 18153 18152 18151 18149 18147 18146 18145 18144 18143 18142 16246 16245#012”


to clear buffers, the SIGUSR2 command was sent to all child processes. and one of them was falling, and the main stream was rebooting.